# call normal WCF service using Jquery

Tags: jquery, wcf

I have a WCF service using the wsHttpBinding. How do i call this service using jquery?
thanks

Please note that this WCF is **NOT** RESTful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to make an assumption that your service is a RESTful URL and that the service returns a JSON result:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://MyServiceAddress/MyServiceRoute/MyServiceAction',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(response) {

    }
});
```

In jQuery 1.5, you can also use the deferred syntax:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://MyServiceAddress/MyServiceRoute/MyServiceAction',
    dataType: 'json'
});

request.success(function(response) {

});
```

Comment: sorry it is not a restful service (wsHttpBinding cannot be restful, am i right?)

Comment: I believe that it could be restful if you set up your endpoints as such. Regardless any URL can be used above.

Comment: ok let me try.. anyway is there a way to call non restful wcf service from jquery?

Comment: If it doesnt have a URL it cant be done. The only other way would be to create some service endpoint (be it restful or not) that has a public facing URL which proxies to your wsHttpBinding service.

Comment: the service always have the URL (e.g. http://somesite/someservice.svc/      However within the someservice.svc behind code there is a method getCustomerName() which is not decorated by either webget or webinvoke attribute. How can i call this such a method through Jquery?

Comment: I believe you can still qualify it like a URL: http://somesite/someservice.svc/getCustomerName. Take a look at http://learningbyfailing.com/2008/05/calling-wcf-from-jquery-using-parameters/

Comment: again the sample site you provided using webget attribute on DoWork method. Now my original question is how can i call the DoWork method without the webget or webinvoke attribute?